# Selecting a data range using months and date over a period of years?

Tags: r, date, subset

I am beginner in R. I have a data.frame in which frequencies in one column and dates in other column. I would like to extract counts for two halves of a month, i.e., 1st to 15th and 16th to 31st. The data below is for August Month from 1992 - 2001. I would like to have total counts for two halves (Aug 1 - Aug 15 & Aug 16 - Aug 31). I searched various options in this portal, but could not figure out a way to do it. Please help!!!!

> df
> 1994-08-06 1
> 1994-08-06 1
> 1994-08-07 1
> 1994-08-14 1
> 1994-08-20 1
> 1994-08-23 1
> 1994-08-24 1
> 1995-08-11 1
> 1995-08-12 1
> 1995-08-14 2
> 1995-08-14 1
> 1995-08-21 1
> 1995-08-29 1
> 1995-08-30 1
> 1996-08-11 1
> 1998-08-03 1
> 1998-08-03 1
> 1998-08-26 1
> 1999-08-09 1
> 2000-08-06 1
> 2001-08-22 1
> 2001-08-24 1
> 2001-08-27 1
> 2001-08-28 1
> 2001-08-29 1

The code i used is

```
df1<-subset(df, format.Date(Dates, "%m/%d")=="08-01" & 
                             format.Date(Dates, "%m/%d")=="08-15")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it. I installed packages "tidyverse" and 'lubridate'.

```
df1<-c(day(df$Dates))
 length (df1[df1<=15]) 
 length (df1[df1>15])
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).